# Using correct coordinate system in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, scale-factor

Im doing fyp on sabah & saraawak map. it came without prj file. i manage projected it and its allign to each other. but now i think the map is too small. as in the whole continent is within few hundred meters.

What is wrong here?

Comment: wild guess: you used a projected coordinate system ( meters) for data which had geographic coordinates ( degree minutes)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What is "fyp"?

Comment: @PolyGeo it mean final year project. i had read about the related question but i still don't get the idea. Is there any video may help clarify further?